# Translating IF condition from Excel to R

Tags: r, excel, if-statement

I have the following data

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Date | Temp.10 | values | Criteria |
| 2 | 10/08/2020 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 3 | 11/08/2020 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 4 | 12/08/2020 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 13/08/2020 | 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 6 | 14/08/2020 | 1 | 13 | 0 |
| 7 | 15/08/2020 | 1 | 15 | 0 |
| 8 | 16/08/2020 | 1 | 7 | 1 |
| 9 | 17/08/2020 | 1 | 6 | 1 |
| 10 | 18/08/2020 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 11 | 19/08/2020 | 1 | 25 | 0 |

To meet the criteria (=1) the two previous days must have values higher than 5.
In Excel I would just place my self in cell E4 and type:

```
=IF(AND(D3>5,D2>5),1,0)
```

And then pull down the formula.

I am trying to write this in R, but I am not succeeding!

Help much appreciated thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
your_data %>%
  mutate(
    Criteria = ifelse(lag(values, 1) > 5 & lag(values, 2) > 5, 1, 0)
  )
```

Comment: How come you're lagging by 1 and 2? Why not just `values > 5 & lag(values) > 5`?

Comment: @CaptainHat Gregor is using that because that is what the question author requested, the "two previous days must have values higher than 5".

Comment: @CaptainHat from the question *"To meet the criteria (=1) the two previous days must have values higher than 5"*.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed, thank you @Gregor!

Answer (score 2):

R syntax is quite different from Excel. I'll show you:

#### AND

Excel: `AND(this, that)`

R: `this & that`

### IF

Excel: `IF(condition, expression, otherwise)`

R:

```
if(condition){
expression
} else {
otherwise
}
```

alternatively: `ifelse(condition, expression, otherwise)`

### Indexing

There's no need for, or possibility of, clicking-and-dragging in R. Lots of functions, including `&`, can deal with vectorised input. (But note that `if` does not.)

To index a 'previous' value, you'll need to use the `lag()` function.

The equivalent of `=IF(AND(D3>5,D2>5),1,0)` is just `(lag(D,1) > 5) &  (lag(D,2) > 5))`, where D is a numeric vector.

If your data is a matrix or data.table, you can get D with `df[,4]` where df is the name of your talbe and, as in your example, D is the fourth column. Alternatively if your columns are named, you can use `df[,"D"]`. So the code would be something like:

`(lag(df[,"D"], 1) > 5) & (lag(df[,"D"], 2) > 5)`

The above will return a `logical` vector with `TRUE`/`FALSE` values. If you want 1's and 0's, put the whole thing inside `as.numeric()`.

Comment: Thanks @Capitan Hat - This is a great explanation to understand what I am doing. I find myself very often coding in a way I don't truly understand so really appreciate your time giving background to the code!!